# Using Google MobileNets in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

Is there a way to test out the pretrained image classification models released by Google called 'MobileNets' using only the Keras API?

Models like ResNet50 and InceptionV3 are already available as Keras Applications, but I couldn't find documentation on using custom tensorflow models with Keras. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, there is no direct access via Keras API to it. However, you can find a good interaction of Keras and MobileNets 
[here](https://medium.com/@timanglade/how-hbos-silicon-valley-built-not-hotdog-with-mobile-tensorflow-keras-react-native-ef03260747f3).